# How to proxy file uploads with multipart/form-data using nginx from XHR to Laravel on windows?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, multipartform-data, firewall

I have searched for more than a day for the same type of problem on the net, and almost tried all the solutions, however I could not get to the solution.

**Situation:** I have a domain, whose A record is pointed to my public IP address, that runs a windows server 2012 R2. On port 80 I have nginx to proxy http request (we are not concerned regarding https for now). nginx will proxy the request to apache virtual hosts, apache itself running on port 9090.

The application that we run has Angular 4 in front end and Laravel 5.6 in back end, however, as Angular 4's httpClient has some problems sending multipart/form-data request that we wanted to use for file upload, we have used plain XHR for POST and PUT requests.

Also I need to mention I have freshly downloaded the pre-build pack from the website using this [link](https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.14.0.zip), i.e. I have not built it from source code.

**Actual behavior:** When sending such POST and PUT requests with the mentioned set up, we do not get response back from the server. Also we have the following states too:

- We can send POST and PUT request without file to the server even with multipart/form data content type, with no problem.
- GET and DELETE requests works fine.
- If I remove the proxy and send the requests directly to the Laravel server, then there is no issue, and the files will be saved (with the sizes of 5 MB to 10 MB that is our desired size), with PUT and POST and multipart/form-data as content type.

**The desired behavior, what we want:** We should be able to send files with POST and PUT requests, like any other methods like GET.

**codes:**

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    sendfile        on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;

    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffers           32 4k;

    server {
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        server_name myhost.net;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://myhost.local:9090;
        }
    }

}
```

Apache vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
    DocumentRoot "C:/path/to/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:9090>
    DocumentRoot "C:/path/to/htdocs/myhost/public"
    ServerName myhost.local
    ServerAlias myhost.net
    ErrorLog "C:/path/to/apache/logs/vhosts/myhost.local-error.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Windows host file, although I do not think it is important:
    127.0.0.1       myhost.local
    ::1             myhost.local

`myhost.net` is routed to public IP as I mentioned from the domain DNS.

Please do let me know if I have missed anything.

### Update 1:

I have been able to find the issue. Firewall, whether windows server firewall or network firewall blocks the traffic. If I turn both the firewalls it works fine, however, any of them is on, and only if we allow HTTP or HTTPS traffic, then again we have the same issue.

This proves that nginx and laravel config are fine, however, still there is a question what is wrong with the requests that makes firewall block them?